# Slow query / disable cache - Sybase Adaptive Server

Tags: database-performance, sqlanywhere

This query seems to be running incredibly slow (25 seconds for 4 million records!) on Sybase v10 at a clients database:

```
Select max(tnr) from myTable;
```

With tnr being the primary key.

If I run it 1000x on our server however, it seems to go fast (15 ms...) which makes me think it's because the query result is cached. Is there a way to disable the cache for this query (or entire database) in Sybase to reproduce this problem?

I tried:

```
call sa_flush_cache ();
call sa_flush_statistics ();
```

But didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't that your results are cached, but that there is a problem with your client's server

Comment: Maybe check both query plans to make sure they are both using any applicable indexes.  MAX() queries usually benefit from backward index scans.

Comment: Tell the client to upgrade! V10 is so so old and completley out of support, I'm actually amazed there is one still in existance..

Comment: Updating the server isn't really in my hands.
The new Sybase EBF now has our queries runing a 1000x slower (they stopped using some indexes)...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately dbcc cacheremove will not work as it does not clear down the pages from cache but rather removes the descriptor and places it back on the free chain.

Aside from restarting the data server the only way to do this is to bind the object to a cache and then do your tests then unbind the object which will remove all the pages from cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dbcc cacheremove`